# using dplyr summarise() with across() with glue-based formatting does not produce column names as expected

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

In R, I am trying to aggregate multiple columns by computing multiple summary statistics. I also want to use `.names` argument in `across()` function so as the outcome `tibble` object has column names that carry information about what summary function was used.

I tried

```
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)

penguins_stats <- penguins %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(species) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(across(.cols = ends_with("mm"), 
                          .fns = list(~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                      ~sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE)),
                          .names = "{.col}_{.fn}"))
```

but the output produced has column names with `_1` and `_2` suffixes instead of `_mean` and `_sd` as I'd expect.

```
names(penguins_stats)
# [1] "species"             "bill_length_mm_1"   
# [3] "bill_length_mm_2"    "bill_depth_mm_1"    
# [5] "bill_depth_mm_2"     "flipper_length_mm_1"
# [7] "flipper_length_mm_2"
```

Session info:

```
sessionInfo()
# R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
# Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
# Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.7
# 
# Matrix products: default
# BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
# LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
# 
# locale:
# [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
# 
# attached base packages:
# [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
# [7] base     
# 
# other attached packages:
# [1] palmerpenguins_0.1.0 forcats_0.5.0       
# [3] stringr_1.4.0        dplyr_1.0.2         
# [5] purrr_0.3.4          readr_1.4.0         
# [7] tidyr_1.1.2          tibble_3.0.4        
# [9] ggplot2_3.3.2        tidyverse_1.3.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass named argument to `.fns` to use `{.fn}` in `.names` :

```
library(dplyr)
penguins_stats <- penguins %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(species) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(across(.cols = ends_with("mm"), 
                          .fns = list(mean = ~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                      sd = ~sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE)),
                          .names = "{.col}_{.fn}"))

names(penguins_stats)
#[1] "species"                "bill_length_mm_mean"    "bill_length_mm_sd"     
#[4] "bill_depth_mm_mean"     "bill_depth_mm_sd"       "flipper_length_mm_mean"
#[7] "flipper_length_mm_sd"
```

However, if you pass a named argument you don't need `.names` at all here.

```
penguins_stats <- penguins %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(species) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(across(.cols = ends_with("mm"), 
                          .fns = list(mean = ~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                      sd = ~sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE))))
names(penguins_stats)

#[1] "species"                "bill_length_mm_mean"    "bill_length_mm_sd"     
#[4] "bill_depth_mm_mean"     "bill_depth_mm_sd"       "flipper_length_mm_mean"
#[7] "flipper_length_mm_sd"
```